# Why the `update` hook doesn’t work on a non-bare repository

Tags: git

I was playing with git hooks, more specifically the `update` hook to be able to [reject misformatted commit message](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy).

So I created an `update` hooks. If I copy this file into `hooks/` folder of a bare repository it does work perfectly and misformatted commits are rejected. But if I copy it into `.git/hooks` folder of a non-bare repository and try to push in this non-bare repository the script is ignored and misformatted commits are added to the repo.

Why? What should I do?

Since my `update` script is versioned into a `scripts` folder, I also tried to set `git config --local core.hooksPath scripts` but this doesn’t work either. Using `core.hooksPath` works perfectly for my `commit-msg` hook on the client side.

---

In case this is an X/Y problem, what I’m trying to do is to be able to enforce a commit message policy automatically, and to make it easy to update that policy. So being able to just commit some files and push them to have that policy updated would be nice (I think I will need to add a `git switch -d HEAD` in the `post-update` hook or something similar to achieve this). I also don’t know why the repo on our shared server at work is a non-bare repository, it’s why I tried to set-up the `update` hook on a non-bare repo.

Answer (score -1):

The update hook is only run *in* bare repositories,<sup>1</sup> *by* the `git upload-pack` command (this is the command the server is told to run, when you, from your Git client, run `git push` *to* the server; the server has the bare repository).  Ordinary commits you make in ordinary repositories never use that hook; instead, they use the pre-commit hook, which would be the place to put such a policy.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it will be run in a non-bare server repository on receipt of a `git push` too, but server repositories generally should be bare, for good reasons.

Comment: That’s exactly my issue. The server isn’t a bare repository, and the `update` doesn’t seems to be run by `git upload-pack` on non-bare repository.

Comment: It should be run unless one of the earlier checks rejects the update. See [`builtin/receive-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/74cc1aa55f30ed76424a0e7226ab519aa6265061/builtin/receive-pack.c#L1557-L1561).

Comment: I assume that if one of the earlier checks rejects the update, an error message should be printed, but I get none.

Comment: Yes, it *should* be printed (and you should get a chance to see it). The thing to do to diagnose this is to watch the `upload-pack` command run, with whatever tracing you can employ (ssh tracing, network packet tracing, logs on the server, whatever is available).